# PDF Reader,thin white line

Tags: ios, pdf

My PDF Reader shows thin white line like this [image]

but this file works fine on acrobat reader and no white line, here is how i handle my pdf file

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 
                                             width, 
                                             height, 
                                             8,                     /* bits per component*/
                                             width * 4,     /* bytes per row */
                                             colorSpace, 
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));

// First fill the background with white.
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context,contentRect);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGContextDrawPDFPage(context,page);
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

What i should do to solve this issue ,
update my code or do something to my PDF file?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)openPDfFile:(CGPDFDocumentRef)pdf
```

{
    // Get the PDF Page that we will be drawing
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageNumer);
    CGPDFPageRetain(page);

```
// determine the size of the PDF page
CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFCropBox);
pdfScale = self.frame.size.height/pageRect.size.height;
pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*pdfScale, pageRect.size.height*pdfScale);


// Create a low res image representation of the PDF page to display before the TiledPDFView
// renders its content.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// First fill the background with white.
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
// Flip the context so that the PDF page is rendered
// right side up.
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// Scale the context so that the PDF page is rendered 
// at the correct size for the zoom level.
CGContextScaleCTM(context, pdfScale,pdfScale);  
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

UIImage *backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
backgroundImageView.frame = pageRect;
backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self addSubview:backgroundImageView];
[self sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];

[self createPage:pageRect];
```

}

-(void)createPage:(CGRect)pageRect
{
    // Create the TiledPDFView based on the size of the PDF page and scale it to fit the view.
    pdfView = [[TiledPDFView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect andScale:pdfScale];
    [pdfView setPage:page];

```
self.frame = pdfView.frame;

[self addSubview:pdfView];
```

}

try these methods !!

Answer (score 1):

This did help in my case

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO); // solves the problem with white lines
```